# Closing an activity on onCreate

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm opening an `Activity` using this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Parent.this, Child.class));
```

And on the child, I have this code on the `onCreate` function (the `if` contains more than just `true`, of course):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (true) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
        builder.setTitle("Error");
        builder.setMessage("Connection error, please try later.")
            .show();
        finishActivity(0);
        return;
    }
}
```

Why is the activity not closing? I get the alert box, but then I have to tap the "back" button to go back.

Comment: Responding here as I'm not 100% certain about this, but have you tried changing that setPositiveButton onClickListener argument to one that calls finish() itself?

Comment: Why would you have an activity just to show a message box?

Comment: @dpk I can do that? I'm not sure how I'd code that...

Comment: @Jason the code is a lot more complicated than the one I posted. The message box would only show if there is a specific error that should almost never happen

Comment: Patrick Boos' code jives what I was talkin' about.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using the [finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) method to close the Activity.

Comment: I do feel stupid for not knowing about `finish()` though. I made it show a `Toast` message, and it looks fine now :)

Comment: toast works because it shows it not as part of the activity. in my other post you can see how you can get it to work with the dialog.

Answer (score 7):

do this in the on create

```
if (true) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null)
           .setTitle("Error")
           .setMessage("Connection error, please try later.")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("_Yes",
                  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                          finish();
                  }
           })
           .show();
    return;
}
```

and in your AndroidManifest.xml do the following:

```
<activity class="MyDialogActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"/>
```

Now you Activity will start and show the Dialog. It feels like there is only the dialog for the user. There is an activity displayed, but it is behind the dialog. So the effect is okay. Otherwise you can create the Dialog in the activity itself (setcontentview).